# Hide photos in the Google+ photos app

Tags: photos, google-plus

I want to back up my photos using the photos app, but I don't want some of them to show up when I open the app on my phone. Is this possible?

Comment: This is exactly my concern, too.  I let my kids use my phone all the time.  Sometimes they want to look at the pictures, take camera photos, etc.  I don't really want them rummaging through all the pics that I have stored on Google+ Photos.

Answer (score 3):

Install file manager

Locate folder where backed up photos are

Put a .nomedia file in that folder

(A .nomedia file is an empty file with no code, which hides media in that folder. To get it you can copy paste it from elsewhere, like if you have WhatsApp, you can browse to it's media in file manager, go to pictures or videos, then to sent, and it should be there, or just do a search in your file manager for .nomedia, or you can make the file yourself)

Go to settings, apps, media storage, and clear it's data.

Restart your phone, go to gallery.

You might need to wait a bit for photos and videos to show up, because you cleared media storage, but the photos in the folder with the .nomedia file won't show up.

Comment: Thanks. However, the pictures are not on my device. They are backed up in the Google Photos cloud. My goal here is when I open the photos app some of the pictures are not seen in the photos app.